# Reward value calculation: Q-Learning

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, reward-system

I am currently working on optimizing reward values for the Q-Learning I'm doing. So right now I consider two values that calculate a specific reward value. Since this is work related i can't specify the variable names i take into consideration. the reward takes the form: `reward = a + b` where `a` takes values from a `list: [10, 20, 40, 60, 80]` and `b` can be any value ranging from `0 to infinity` ie `b ε [0,∞)`. Even though the value of b will not be so large, it can take any value within the range.

So the situation is such that: if the b is something like `b=1300` and `a=80`, the `reward = 1380` where the priority of value `a` gets eclipsed by `b`. Is there someway I can formulate reward such that both the values of a and b have equal priority like both having 50% value while calculating reward?

Answer (score 1):

One technique that I would recommend which should solve your problem is to **[regularize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) the Q-values** for both a and b. There are lots of ways to do just that, but I think **L1 or L2 regularization** should solve your problem nicely.

In short, L2 regularization is a mathematical equation that calculates the sum of the square of the weights.

[image: l2 regularization formula]

The image above is from [chioka.in](http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-l1-and-l2-as-loss-function-and-regularization/).

Comment: But could you help me citing an example.Something like, initially my value for a particular data point is 0. Then for the same data point the reward value is found to have `a=80` and `b=1300` (just an example). Then how would I regularize the Q-value at this instance? Just that I did not get a clarity here.